# Queue in normal linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I want to merge `N` ordered linked lists into one ordered linked list.

However, I also want the individual ordered linked list to be retained. I am successful in doing so using an array of `Node` pointers with each array element as a node corresponding to first node of individual lists. However, with array size fixed, I cannot proceed with merging more than array size.

Now my question is, is there a way I can dynamically change array size. If not I am thinking of using Queue instead to hold the first node of individual lists in a queue linked list. Am I going right or wrong? Please give me some tips regarding the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for `realloc`, assuming you dynamically allocated your array in the first place.

Comment: Yes that solves it. Thanks I cannot believe I was procrastinating to learn such an easy thing. :)